# How do I store an unsigned short into a char array? C language

Tags: c, arm, code-composer

I'm a beginner in C language, I was wondering how I store an unsigned short into a char array?

unit16_t is unsigned short, and below is my code.

```
uint16_t  combined = 1234;
char echoPrompt[] = {combined};
```

EDIT:

Sorry for being unclear 
I need echoPrompt to be a char array and combined needs to be an integer. I am passing echPrompt as a char array to a UART_write which required a char array.

Comment: You'll need to add more info on why you need to do this. Short answer is why not use an array of shorts?

Comment: Hi John, please see above

Comment: Please give more details about the issue. There are at least two different methods depending on the details.

Comment: Are you storing little or big endian?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass an array to a function. You can pass a pointer. Pointers are not arrays.

If your UART_write looks anything like any of the standard C/POSIX functions `write`, `fwrite` etc, you need

```
  result = UART_write (..., 
        (char*)&combined, 
        sizeof(combined), ...);
```

There is no need in a char array.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly, you want to save each upper and lower 1 byte of short in char array.

well, why don't you just use union?

```
typedef struct uint16_s{ 
    char upper; 
    char lower;
} uint16_s;

typedef union uint16_u{
    uint16_s sBuf;
    uint16_t tBuf;
} uint16_u;

uint16_u combined;
combined.tBuf = 1234;
char echoPrompt[] = {combined.sBuf.upper, combined.sBuf.lower};
```